# AddClass/RemoveClass Issues

Tags: jquery

On the click of button with class A, replace class A with class B. On the click of button with class B I need to perform an action.

It's applying/removing the class correctly but for some reason it won't select class B?

```
$(".changebut").click(function () {
   $("input[type=text]").fadeOut("fast", function () {
       $(".changebut").animate({
           width: "100%"
       }, 200).val("Submit again").removeClass("changebut").addClass("submitbut")
    })
}),
$(".submitbut").click(function () {
    alert('it worked!')
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9RuM/1/)

Comment: Try using `toggleClass()`

Comment: Does `toggleClass` work in IE8 ?

Comment: Use event delegation. Otherwise your click handler will only ever be bound to whatever is currently with the provided class when the surrounding function runs.

Comment: @JordanThompson tried toggleClass() with no luck

Comment: Here is the fix using an ID instead of the dynamic classes. Your function is called BEFORE the class is changed, so you need a global handle, IE a ID. See: http://jsfiddle.net/B9RuM/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution if to use event delegation instead of direct binding :

```
$(document).on('click', '.changebut', function () {
    $("input[type=text]").fadeOut("fast", function () {
        $(".changebut").animate({
             width: "100%"
         }, 200).val("Submit again").removeClass("changebut").addClass("submitbut")
    });
})

$(document).on('click', '.submitbut', function () {
    alert('it worked!')
})
```

The best solution is to bind the click event directly and check for the current class :

```
$(".changebut").on('click', function () {
    if($(this).is('.changebut')){
        $("input[type=text]").fadeOut("fast", function () {
            $(".changebut").animate({
                width: "100%"
            }, 200).val("Submit again").removeClass("changebut").addClass("submitbut")
        });
    }else{
        alert('i have an other class');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a single event binding that handles both actions.

```
$(".changebut,.submitbut").click(function () {
   if ($(this).is(".changebut")) {
       $("input[type=text]").fadeOut("fast", function () {
           $(".changebut").animate({
               width: "100%"
           }, 200).val("Submit again").removeClass("changebut").addClass("submitbut")
       });
    } else {
        alert("It worked!");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I did the dv, i don't recall your answer having the second half originally, which is why i downvoted. i disagree with the event delegation solution to this unless it specifically uses a close parent element rather than document. dv has been revoked

Comment: I upvoted this because it's rather neat to use a single event handler rather than 2. Then again I have no idea why all the other answers (which also work) got downvoted.

Comment: @KevinB Thank for explaining ;) but as i said, the delegation was the *easy fix*.

Answer (score -1):

Use event delegation. Added semicolons, too:

```
$(document).on('click', ".changebut", function () {
   $("input[type=text]").fadeOut("fast", function () {
      $(".changebut").animate({
           width: "100%"
      }, 200).val("Submit again").removeClass("changebut").addClass("submitbut");
   });
});
$(document).on('click', ".submitbut", function () {
   alert('it worked!');
});
```